# Hello World - Using Angular 2 - TypeScript stuck at Loading

Tags: angular, typescript

Error in the browsers log shows

> node_modules/angular2/platform/browser.d.ts(78,90): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise' requires 2 type argument(s).

Comment: Can you add more code snippet of the component

Comment: Ahow your code! and read [ask] to improve your question. Hint: `Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s).`

Comment: Error is hsowing in browser.d.ts as `d.ts` the issue seems to be in typings issue

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your typescript compiler is looking in your `node_modules` folder or you have that file open somewhere whilst building. Try excluding it in your `tsconfig` file

```
"exclude": [
    "node_modules"
]
```

Comment: i have already excluded mode_modules in tsconfig {
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "outDir": "built"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}

Comment: The only other place I have referred other components is in Package.json

Comment: {
\  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "^2.0.0-beta.21",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.0-beta.6",
    "systemjs": "^0.20.10",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.17"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.2.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.3.0",
    "typings": "^2.1.0"
  }
}

Comment: Is this causing any problem

Comment: No, that shouldn't cause a problem. Make sure you're using the latest versions of Typescript and Typings, I can't really help much as there is too little information about your set up to understand what's going on